# Difference between get and []

Tags: python

New to Django, can someone explain the difference between

```
username=form.cleaned_data['username']
```

**vs**

```
username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
```

Comment: This is not a Django question, `cleaned_data` is a standard Python dict.

Comment: @ user1833746 its hard to search for something when you don't know what so search for! I have only been playing around with Django for a few weeks (actually days if you add it up) so this question was very helpful and the answer very clear. I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will raise a `KeyError` if `username` key is not found

```
form.cleaned_data['username']
```

But this will return `None` (by default) if key is not found, does not raises `KeyError` exception.

```
form.cleaned_data.get('username')
```

Optionally you can change the default return value (if you use `.get`) if key is not found.

```
val = form.cleaned_data.get('username', False)
# assume key was not found
print val # should contains False now
```

Answer (score 4):

`form.cleaned_data` is a dictionary. If you try to access the key directly through dictionary like this, it would raise an error if the key is not found.

```
>>> ex_dict = {}
>>> ex_dict = {'x':1, 'y':2}
>>> ex_dict['z']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'z'
```

Whereas, if you use `get` with the dictionary, it would return `None` and not the error or you can specify the return you expect if key is not found.

```
>>> ex_dict.get('z')
>>> ex_dict.get('z', 1)
1
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

> `get`(*key*[, *default*])
>
> Return the value for *key* if *key* is in the dictionary, else *default*. If *default* is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`.